# Use closure under addition of positive numbers to prove that a<b => a+c < b+c

Tags: inequality, axioms

I'm starting R.P Burn "Number and Functions, Steps into Analysis". In Chapter 2, the basic properties of inequalities are derived, and question 8 asks to prove *using the fact that positive numbers are closed under addition* that $a<b \Rightarrow a+c<b+c$.

The solution presented in the book is:
$a<b \Rightarrow  0<b-a \Rightarrow  0 < (b+c) - (a+c) \Rightarrow  a+c < b+c$

Where is the property that the positive numbers are closed under addition used in this proof? It seems to me like it's just adding $+c$ and $-c$ to both sides of the inequality, which works but I don't see how it relies on the closure property.

Comment: The last implication requires that both $a+c$ and $b+c$ are real numbers.

Comment: See [Closed under an operation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687230/closed-under-an-operation)